# Multiple iOS libraries each with their own Core Data storage

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm currently using Magical Record to handle Core Data storage within a static iOS library. I'm now working on a new library which requires Core Data and would like to use Magical Record for this again, it is likely both libraries will be used in the same application. The data model for both libraries will be different (they are responsible for persisting different things) and there doesn't need to be any interaction between the libraries with regard to Core Data.

So my Goal is two static libraries with different data to persist both handling there own Core Data storage while being used in the same application.

My question is how can I achieve this using Magical Record?

Obviously as individual libraries everything is fine but what will happen when there both used in the same application.

I should point out I'm relatively new to iOS development so I only having a small amount of knowledge about Core Data and Magical Panda.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the current release version of MagicalRecord has quite a hard time with this specific scenario. Which is why I've been working on MagicalRecord 3.0. Have a look in the **[release/3.0](https://github.com/magicalpanda/magicalrecord/tree/release/3.0)** branch on the github repo. MagicalRecord 3.0 is in a beta state, but all the functionality from the previous version is working. MagicalRecord 3.0 introduces the concept of a stack, which is what you will be using to implement this scenario. I've also removed all the default object categories from the core data stack, and instead manage a default stack within MagicalRecord itself. This means if you want to "upgrade" an app from 2.x to 3.0, you'll need to go through and fix a bunch of references. But, since you're working on a new project, I recommend giving it a try. I plan to spend some time soon to make MagicalRecord a releasable library.

Comment: Have you got an example that uses the stack concept? Could you explain a bit about it and how it relates to the multiple library problem?

Comment: @casademora very interested in a example aswell

Comment: An example will be posted to the repo eventually. It's slow going since I'm working on quite a number of things at the moment.